# Test onOk / onCancel | Ant Design [antd]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, antd

Is there any way to test onOk and onCancel ? I've already tried to test onCancel using ***fireEvent.keyDown*** but it doesn't work as I expect.

```
 <>
  <AntdModal
    data-testid="modal-window"
    width={583}
    visible={visible}
    onOk={() => setVisible(false)}
    onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
    closable={false}
    header={null}
    footer={null}
  >
    <span className="modal-header">
      {headerText}
    </span>
    {children}
  </AntdModal>
</>
```

The main reason why I'd like to test this one It's because I need to cover my tests more than 80%...

[coverage result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNY26.png)

*.test.js:

```
  it('should modal disappear after cancel click', async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <ModalWindow headerText="header" setVisible={jest.fn} visible>
        <div>children</div>
      </ModalWindow>,
    );

    const modal = screen.getByTestId('modal-window');
    expect(modal).toBeInTheDocument();

    fireEvent.keyDown(container, {
      key: 'Escape',
      code: 'Escape',
      keyCode: 27,
      charCode: 27,
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(modal).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

Comment: What's the test result?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about code coverage (and in your case about code smell), I would suggest to declare `() => setVisible(false)` as constant. This will reduce a (possible bug generating) code duplicate and you will not need to test foreign libraries in your code.

Comment: The question isn't about code style, it's only about testing, and using a constant won't solve the problem in any way.